# How to fix Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working with clock.js, but as I am testing the clock.js library I continue to receive an error.

Here's my code...

```
function getTimes()
{
    moment.tz.add(['Eire|GMT IST|0 -10|01010101010101010101010|1BWp0 1qM0 
    WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 
    1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00',
    'Asia/Tokyo|JST|-90|0|',
    'America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0']);

var now=new Date();
var times=[
            {jsclass:'js-tokyo',jstime:moment.tz(now,"Asia/Tokyo")},
            {jsclass:'js-london',jstime:moment.tz(now,"Eire")},
            {jsclass:'js-new-york',jstime:moment.tz(now,"America/New_York")}
          ];
return times;
}
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
> at getTimes (VM217 clock.js:1)
>
> at initInternationalClocks (VM217 clock.js:2)
>
> at VM217 clock.js:1
>
> at VM217 clock.js:1

How can I resolve following errors?

Comment: as the error says, you don't have `moment` library included in your project

Comment: moment is an external library, you must include it before executing your script, see the documentation at https://momentjs.com/

Comment: where is your `clock.js` file reference ?